# Operating system scanner

Tags: operating-systems, vulnerability-scanners

I am confused about Operating Systems scanner vs Network Scanner. Usually a network scanner such as Nessus can already check for operating systems vulnerability. So what does an operating system scanner do? Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: If Nessus is a "network scanner", what's an example of an "operating system scanner"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A network scanner interrogates the target over the network:

- determines open ports via (semi-)exhaustive search
- determines software and versions, if possible, based on banners and behavior
- checks for known vulnerabilities (e.g., does /CFIDE/administrator exist)

but it is limited by only having network access.  The banner printed on port 22 will identify the SSH version, but this can be misleading - if the OS vendor has backported security fixes (common practice), then the banner may *indicate* an older, vulnerable version when in fact the software is newer enough to be invulnerable to those issues.

An operating system scanner uses local credentials to access the system *from the inside*.

- determines listening ports looking at the OS tools (e.g. netstat)
- queries exact software installations and versions
- queries installed patches and file versions to see if vulnerabilities are patched

The operating system scanner is much more complete and accurate as a result.

There are a number of scanners that fall into this category to various degrees.  I can't recommend one (so many and so different) but they fall into two main categories:

Scanners or scanning services that performs ["authenticated", "trusted", or "credentialed" scans](http://www.securityweek.com/z-vulnerability-management-authenticated-scanning); these will generally check OS configuration, patches, and installed software.

- [Qualys **trusted** scan](https://qualysguard.qualys.com/qwebhelp/fo_help/authentication/about_trusted_scanning.htm)
- Rapid7 Nexpose **authenticated** scan

Tools which authenticated users run locally:

- Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer (checks versions and patches for MS products)
- [Qualys BrowserCheck](https://browsercheck.qualys.com) (checks browsers, limited (web-related) software, OS patches, and certain OS configuration details like firewall and AV configured)

This latter "tools" category tends to be more limited in scope; for the fullest coverage, look for a scanner that supports either enterprise or cloud-based scope.  (Arguably no one is going to sink the time and money into a tool that they sell for individual system users; the money is in the people who need to use it to protect entire networks).

Comment: What do you mean by "if the OS vendor has backported security fixes"?